# can't find three consecutive words in string using findall

Tags: python, regex

I was trying to find names in given text using findall() method. when i use search() method
i was getting name present in the text but findall was not working at all.

given text is :

i was trying to find those names in BOLD

R120221325      **ARYAN BAJAJ YASHWARDHAN**                               MANISHA                        716012335X   SMDS                                                                                  Grd   Crd               IN       TH     [IN+TH]     TW       PR       OR    Tot% Crd  Grd  Pts   Pts             ~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~  ~~~  ~~   ~~~  ~~    ~~ SEM.:1    406261    021/030  043/070  064/100  -------  -------  -------  64   04   A    08    32   406261    -------  -------  -------  -------  040/050  -------  80   01   O    10    10   406262    018/030  046/070  064/100  -------  -------  -------  64   03   A    08    24   406262    -------  -------  -------  -------  -------  040/050  80   01   O    10    10   406263    019/030  055/070  074/100  -------  -------  -------  74   03   A+   09    27   406263    -------  -------  -------  042/050  -------  -------  84   01   O    10    10  406264D    024/030  043/070  067/100  -------  -------  -------  67   03   A    08    24  406264D    -------  -------  -------  -------  -------  040/050  80   01   O    10    10  406265D    016/030  050/070  066/100  -------  -------  -------  66   03   A    08    24   406266    -------  -------  -------  045/050  -------  -------  90   02   O    10    20  410249C    -------  -------  -------       PP  -------  -------  PP   00   P    00    00  SEM.:2    406268 *  020/030  034/070  054/100  -------  -------  -------  54   03   B    06    18   406268 *  -------  -------  -------  -------  -------  044/050  88   01   O    10    10   406269 *  023/030  047/070  070/100  -------  -------  -------  70   03   A+   09    27   406269 *  -------  -------  -------  -------  -------  043/050  86   01   O    10    10  406270C *  024/030  053/070  077/100  -------  -------  -------  77   03   A+   09    27  406270C *  -------  -------  -------  -------  -------  040/050  80   01   O    10    10  406271B *  024/030  045/070  069/100  -------  -------  -------  69   03   A    08    24   406273 *  -------  -------  -------  092/100  -------  -------  92   04   O    10    40   406273 *  -------  -------  -------  -------  -------  047/050  94   02   O    10    20   406274 *  -------  -------  -------  042/050  -------  -------  84   01   O    10    10  FOURTH YEAR SGPA : 8.8, TOTAL CREDITS EARNED : 44     B150084606        **DHAIRYA YASHRAJ SALUNKE**                             HEENA                          716012335X   SMDS                                                                                  Grd   Crd               IN       TH     [IN+TH]     TW       PR       OR    Tot% Crd  Grd  Pts   Pts             ~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~  ~~~  ~~   ~~~  ~~    ~~ SEM.:1    406261    019/030  046/070  065/100  -------  -------  -------  65   04   A    08    32   406261    -------  -------  -------  -------  041/050  -------  82   01   O    10    10   406262    022/030  047/070  069/100  -------  -------  -------  69   03   A    08    24   406262    -------  -------  -------  -------  -------  043/050  86   01   O    10    10   406263    021/030  050/070  071/100  -------  -------  -------  71   03   A+   09    27   406263    -------  -------  -------  045/050  -------  -------  90   01   O    10    10  406264D *  025/030  040/070  065/100  -------  -------  -------  65   03   A    08    24  406264D    -------  -------  -------  -------  -------  045/050  90   01   O    10    10  406265D    024/030  044/070  068/100  -------  -------  -------  68   03   A    08    24   406266    -------  -------  -------  043/050  -------  -------  86   02   O    10    20  410249C    -------  -------  -------       PP  -------  -------  PP   00   P    00    00  SEM.:2    406268 *  012/030  038/070  050/100  -------  -------  -------  50   03   B    06    18   406268 *  -------  -------  -------  -------  -------  041/050  82   01   O    10    10   406269 *  021/030  045/070  066/100  -------  -------  -------  66   03   A    08    24   406269 *  -------  -------  -------  -------  -------  045/050  90   01   O    10    10  406270C *  020/030  046/070  066/100  -------  -------  -------  66   03   A    08    24  406270C *  -------  -------  -------  -------  -------  040/050  80   01   O    10    10  406271B *  020/030  044/070  064/100  -------  -------  -------  64   03   A    08    24   406273 *  -------  -------  -------  096/100  -------  -------  96   04   O    10    40   406273 *  -------  -------  -------  -------  -------  047/050  94   02   O    10    20   406274 *  -------  -------  -------  042/050  -------  -------  84   01   O    10    10  FOURTH YEAR SGPA : 8.66, TOTAL CREDITS EARNED : 44

regular expression i wrote was :

```
re.compile(r'\s{1,}\w*\s{1,}?\w*\s{1,}?\w*\s{1,}').findall()
```

with findall i was getting list of empty strings

what i was trying to do here is to find three consecutive names in text separated by mininal whitespace. as there are only two names like that in whole text but i was not getting desired output instead i was getting list full of empty values .
 but search was giving me correct output but i wanted two matches here and search only returns first match it finds.

i was able to get this after reducing this whole text to very minimum and then including values between two 8 digit number followed by a character(like here R120221325 , 716012335X)

but if i can get answer without reducing text to minimum it will save lots of trouble .

sorry for such long question but i am unable to find its answer i tried for so long .

any help is appreciated .

Comment: I believe you'd need to search for at least 2 or more spaces. So something like: `\s{2,}(?:[A-Z]+\s){3}` might work. Obviously trim the resulting values. A longer version with lookarounds could be: `(?<=\s\s)(?:[A-Z]+\s){2}[A-Z]+(?=\s\s)`

Comment: thanks man it worked . thanks a lot man i was totally dead while getting a solution @JvdV . where can i learn more about these expressions like (?:, ?= ,?<=  etc.)

Comment: I really like [this](https://regular-expressions.mobi/index.html?wlr=1) website. Look for non-capture groups and lookarounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might make use of the difference in the numbers of spacing.

The values are in the first capturing group.

```
\b[A-Z]\d{9}\s+((?:\w+\s)+\w+)(?:\s{2,}\w+)+\s+\d{9}[A-Z]\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` Word boundary
- `[A-Z]\d{9}\s+` Match A-Z, 9 digits (instead of 8 digit number)
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:\w+\s)+\w+` Repeat 1+ times matching 1+ word chars and a single whitespace char followed by 1+ word chars
- `)` Close group 1
- `(?:\s{2,}\w+)+` Repeat 1+ times matching 2 or more whitespace chars and 1+ word chars
- `\s+\d{9}[A-Z]` Match 1+ whitespace chars followed by 9 digits and a char A-Z
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5lHRN9/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/aSMcai)

Comment: Thank you . It works perfect . Thanks again for the nice explaination

Answer (score -1):

That's because `\w*` matches **any** number of word chars **including 0**, so your regexp matched on three consecutive spaces.

Change your regex to:

```
r'\b[A-Z]+\s+[A-Z]+\s+[A-Z]+\b'
```

`+` means **1 or more** occurrences, rather than zero or more.

Comment: OP says they want to match `ARYAN BAJAJ YASHWARDHAN` and `DHAIRYA YASHRAJ SALUNKE`. [Your regex does not do that](https://regex101.com/r/9wdPPc/1).

Comment: Does not do the trick as the thre words which have the minimum number of spaces between them should be found. Like @WiktorStribiżew said

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew right, I have missed alphanumerical strings without punctuation chars in OP's example. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: (of course it still matches "TOTAL CREDITS EARNED"…)